# How to check if a file in GCP Storage is public or not?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is there any way to check if a file in GCP Cloud Storage is public or private in Python?

The GCP Docs [Here](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.make_public) has functions to `make_public` or `make_private` but couldn't find anything to check if a file is public or not.

Answer (score 6):

Google Cloud Storage has two systems of controlling access. IAM and ACLs. Both can be used at the same time except if the next feature is enabled.

Buckets support **uniform** bucket level access (aka Bucket Policy Only) which disables ACLs.

The following example first processes a bucket. If uniform access is not enabled then the object is also processed. If public access is enabled on the bucket or the object, the object is Public.

[Download example code below from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/jhanley-com/3fca04a065ebf54cf42bcc70be98b387)

[Uniform bucket-level access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access)

[Identity and Access Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam)

[Access control lists (ACLs)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists)

```
import  sys
from google.cloud import storage

# Replace with valid bucket and object names
bucket_name = 'example_bucket_name'
object_name = 'example_object_name'

# Instantiates a client
storage_client = storage.Client()

# Process bucket level access
def process_bucket(bucketName):
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucketName)

    configuration = bucket.iam_configuration
    uniformEnabled = configuration['uniformBucketLevelAccess']['enabled']

    public = False

    policy = bucket.get_iam_policy()

    for binding in policy.bindings:
        for m in binding['members']:
            if m == 'allUsers':
                public = True

    print('Bucket:', bucketName)
    print('  Uniform Access:', uniformEnabled)
    print('  Public:', public)

    return uniformEnabled

# Process blob level access
def process_object(bucketName, objectName):
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucketName)

    blob = bucket.blob(objectName)

    policy = blob.get_iam_policy()

    public = False

    for binding in policy.bindings:
        for m in binding['members']:
            if m == 'allUsers':
                public = True

    print('Object: gs://{0}/{1}'.format(bucketName, objectName))
    print('  Public:', public)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        uniform_enabled = process_bucket(bucket_name)
        if uniform_enabled is False:
            process_object(bucket_name, object_name)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Exception: {}".format(ex), file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: This should be flagged as the answer :D

Comment: So this is not strictly accurate, in that a bucket can have fine-grained control enabled, but still be public as the default. We use one for hosting images with exactly that setting. No object has an iam permission for allUsers, but they all inherit `roles/storage.objectViewer`.

Comment: @JasonNichols - which settings did you apply to the bucket/objects?

Comment: Public to Internet is on bucket. Not sure if from there `allUsers` is assigned the role `Storage Object Viewer` or we assigned it manually. No permissions have been set on the individual files. The buckets were set up about a year ago, and I hadn't looked until just now when I was testing this script.

Comment: @JasonNichols Did you find an issue with the Python code? I do not understand what problem you found.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you shared is actually for the Bucket, not the File itself (represented by Blobs in the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html)), however, the Blob also has the `make_public` and `make_private` function but no function to check whether the file is public.

An alternative for this would be to use the `public_url` property with a anonymous client, if the file is not public this is going to throw an error that you can catch (which is not ideal but doable).

Another possibility would be to have 2 separate buckets, one for public access and one for private access. This would likely be the better choice.

That being said, having a function to say if the file is public or not sounds like a good idea, so I would advise you to [open a Feature Request at Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=0), so that the product team can consider implementing this.